# PHP Sytax in html has unexpected output

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, I wrote these code from a online courses. But when I open the PHP file in web browser, it was not what I expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>untitled</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Bio</h1>
    <?php>
        echo 'My name is Chao';
        echo Hello World!<br>   
    <?>
    <?php> echo 5+6+7 <?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is: 
echo 'My name is Chao'; echo Hello World!
echo 5+6+7;

I was expecting: echo My name is Chao echo Hello World!
18

Why this is happening? I'm using Microsoft Edge currently.

I'm looking forward for you reply.Thank you.

Comment: Syntax is <?php echo 'Myname is Chao'; ?>  Remove > after "<?php" and remove < before "?>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making php syntax error here.

php starts with `<?php`

ends with `?>`

Note: Hello world should be within a quote, `echo` must end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Php code has following syntax. Make sure you file has .php extension.
Also your expected result should be "My name is Chao Hello World! 18" and not "echo My name is Chao echo Hello World! 18", since echo is command to print those string.

```
<?php /* php code here */ ?>
```

Change your code this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>untitled</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Bio</h1>
    <?php
        echo 'My name is Chao';
        echo 'Hello World!<br>' ;//note the quotes
        echo 5+6+7 ;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

php is server side programming , it start with `<?php` and close with `?>` and it can't run on html file , so if you will programming use php language use php file

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    echo 'My name is Chao<br>';
    echo 'Hello World!<br>';

    echo 5+6+7;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated code
Errors in your code explained in the comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>untitled</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Bio</h1>
    <?php //php code start with `<?php`
        echo 'My name is Chao';
        echo 'Hello World!<br>';   // a string must within a ' or ". 
    //php code end with `?>`
?>
        <?php echo (5+6+7); ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```